# How is template class inherited child classes in GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc, clang

I don't understand GCC and Clang behavior in the following code example.
Why GCC/Clang allows calling not inherited classes like check<'d'>.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<char TCh> struct check { static constexpr char ch = TCh; };
template<char ... TChs> struct checker
    : public check<TChs>...
{};

using double_litters = checker<'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.'>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << double_litters::check<'d'>::ch << std::endl;  // GCC/Clang compile OK, VS compile ERROR
    std::cout << double_litters::check<'1'>::ch << std::endl;  // GCC/Clang compile OK, VS compile OK
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MSVS 19.21 compiles this code. What version are you using?

Comment: I think the question is rather why this snippet can even be compiled by any compiler, as it refers to a base class that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I guess MSVS work correctly, GCC and Clang processing this case strange.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this happens and if this is actually an error. But you can fix it like this:

```
double_litters().check<'d'>::ch
```

This will give error in GCC, don't have clang to check...